# Run .BAT when a file is detected

Tags: batch-file

trying to create a .bat file to detect a file and execute a command

at the moment I am running the .bat file manually, want it to run automatically when it detect file is created

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\\Garment Label\CSVProcessor\CSVProcessor.Host.exe"  CSVConfig 
"C:\Users\Desktop\Label\Revised 150718\test2.csv"
DEL "C:\Users\Desktop\Label\Revised 150718\test2.csv"
```

Thank you

Comment: And what is your question? please be precise! what about a Scheduled Task for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what file you want to check or if you want it to constantly run and delete the file, so I will give you two options.

If file doesn't exist, close batch.

```
:retest
if not exist "C:\Users\Desktop\Label\Revised 150718\test2.csv" (
goto :NoFile
) else (
    DEL "C:\Users\Desktop\Label\Revised 150718\test2.csv"
    Echo Deleting file
    goto :retest
)
:NoFile
```

Loop and constantly delete a file if it exists, waiting 10 seconds between loops.

```
:retest
if not exist "C:\Users\Desktop\Label\Revised 150718\test2.csv" (
timeout 10
goto :retest
) else (
    DEL "C:\Users\Desktop\Label\Revised 150718\test2.csv"
    Echo Deleting file
    goto :retest
)
```

Comment: Hi, I want to check if the file test2 exists, if so run CSVProcessor.Host.exe and delete file .

Comment: Then throw it under the `) else (` line to run your exe.